# BigQuery how to use MERGE to load array columns

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a test table that I am trying to load from GCS storage:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ta_producer_conformed.test
(
  id NUMERIC,
  array_string ARRAY<STRING>,
  array_struct_string_string ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING,  value STRING>>,
  array_struct_string_numeric ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING,  value NUMERIC>>,
  array_struct_string_int64 ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING,  value INT64>>
)
```

I have defined an external storage table as:

```
{
  "autodetect": true, 
  "csvOptions": {
    "encoding": "UTF-8", 
    "quote": "\"",
    "fieldDelimiter": "\t"
  }, 
  "sourceFormat": "CSV", 
  "sourceUris": [
    "gs://my_bucket/test/input/*.tsv"
  ]
}
```

In it I am using JSON to hold the ARRAY types:

```
"id"    "array_string"  "struct_string_string"  "struct_string_numberic"    "struct_string_int64"
1   ["one", "two", "three"] [{"key":"one", "value":"1"},{"key":"two", "value":"2"},{"key":"three", "value":"3"}]    [{"key":"one", "value":1.1},{"key":"two", "value":2.2}] [{"key":"one", "value":11},{"key":"two", "value":22}]
2   ["four", "five", "six"] [{"key":"four", "value":"4"},{"key":"five", "value":"5"},{"key":"six", "value":"6"}]    [{"key":"three", "value":3.3},{"key":"four", "value":4.4}]  [{"key":"three", "value":33},{"key":"four", "value":44}]
```

I then want to using a MERGE to upsert the data in the target table. When I run this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION ARRAY_OF(json STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  let parsed = JSON.parse(json);
  return parsed;
""";
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION ARRAY_STRUCT_STRING_STRING_OF(json STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRING>>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  let parsed = JSON.parse(json);
  return parsed;
""";
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION ARRAY_STRUCT_STRING_NUMERIC_OF(json STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value NUMERIC>>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  let parsed = JSON.parse(json);
  return parsed;
""";
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION ARRAY_STRUCT_STRING_INT64_OF(json STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value INT64>>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  let parsed = JSON.parse(json);
  return parsed;
""";
MERGE ta_producer_conformed.test T
USING ta_producer_raw.test_raw S
ON
    S.id = T.id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, array_string, array_struct_string_string, array_struct_string_numeric, array_struct_string_int64)
    VALUES (
        id, 
        ARRAY_OF(array_string), 
        ARRAY_STRUCT_STRING_STRING_OF(struct_string_string),
        ARRAY_STRUCT_STRING_NUMERIC_OF(struct_string_numberic),
        ARRAY_STRUCT_STRING_INT64_OF(struct_string_int64)
    )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
        T.id = S.id, 
        T.array_string = ARRAY_OF(S.array_string), 
        T.struct_string_string = ARRAY_STRUCT_STRING_STRING_OF(S.struct_string_string),
        T.ARRAY_STRUCT_STRING_NUMERIC_OF(S.struct_string_numberic),
        T.ARRAY_STRUCT_STRING_INT64_OF(S.struct_string_int64)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in query string: Error processing job 'xxxx-10843454-datamesh-
dev:bqjob_r4c426875_00000173fcfd2294_1': Syntax error: Expected "." or "=" or
"[" but got "(" at [1:1312]
```

If I delete the whole last section for WHEN MATCHED such that it only INSERTS the temporary functions work fine. So the problem appears to be that in final `THEN UPDATE SET` section I cannot use the temporary functions.

How can I get data types such as `ARRAY<STRING>` and `ARRAY<STRUCT<STRING,STRING>>` to load from an external bucket ideally using a single MERGE statement?

**Update**: I tried to use a Common Table Expression to pre-process the data using:

```
WITH cteConvertJason AS (
  SELECT 
        id, 
        ARRAY_OF(array_string) AS array_string, 
        ARRAY_STRUCT_STRING_STRING_OF(struct_string_string) AS struct_string_string,
        ARRAY_STRUCT_STRING_NUMERIC_OF(struct_string_numberic) AS struct_string_numberic,
        ARRAY_STRUCT_STRING_INT64_OF(struct_string_int64) AS struct_string_int64
  FROM
    ta_producer_raw.test_raw
)
MERGE ta_producer_conformed.test T
USING cteConvertJason S
...
```

That gave an error so it looks like you combine `WITH` and `MERGE`.

**Update:** We were trying out TSV for legacy reasons. It is a far better idea to use `NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON` as the format such that you do not need to explicitly parse the nested or repeated columns.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the `MERGE target USING source` can use a query as the source. That query can run the temporary functions to pre-process the source data. Then the rest of the MERGE statement can be vanilla and works:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION ARRAY_OF(json STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  let parsed = JSON.parse(json);
  return parsed;
""";
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION ARRAY_STRUCT_STRING_STRING_OF(json STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRING>>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  let parsed = JSON.parse(json);
  return parsed;
""";
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION ARRAY_STRUCT_STRING_NUMERIC_OF(json STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value NUMERIC>>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  let parsed = JSON.parse(json);
  return parsed;
""";
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION ARRAY_STRUCT_STRING_INT64_OF(json STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value INT64>>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  let parsed = JSON.parse(json);
  return parsed;
""";
MERGE ta_producer_conformed.test T
USING 
 (
  SELECT 
        id, 
        ARRAY_OF(array_string) AS array_string, 
        ARRAY_STRUCT_STRING_STRING_OF(struct_string_string) AS struct_string_string,
        ARRAY_STRUCT_STRING_NUMERIC_OF(struct_string_numberic) AS struct_string_numberic,
        ARRAY_STRUCT_STRING_INT64_OF(struct_string_int64) AS struct_string_int64
  FROM
    ta_producer_raw.test_raw
)
 S
ON
    S.id = T.id
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (id, array_string, array_struct_string_string, array_struct_string_numeric, array_struct_string_int64)
    VALUES (
        id, 
        array_string, 
        struct_string_string,
        struct_string_numberic,
        struct_string_int64
    )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
        T.array_string = S.array_string, 
        T.array_struct_string_string = S.struct_string_string,
        T.array_struct_string_numeric = S.struct_string_numberic,
        T.array_struct_string_int64 = S.struct_string_int64
```